Force EF6 to use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR in QUERY expressions
Disclaimer - This is both a theoretical and real case question. Legacy and other circumstances makes it real.
The question is:
Can I force EF6 to use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR in QUERY expressions?
One reason could be performance (I know this is probably not the right place to look at performance, see disclaimer), In the DB I'm working at I noticed a significant performance diff. when I used VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR.
Scenario
I have 40.000 id's in a List, and I use them to query my Customers table.
List<string> ids = new[]{"Id1", "Id2" .. "Id40000"}.ToList();
var customers = dbContext.Customers.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Id));

The Id column in the SQL table is VARCHAR(50)
and Customers.Id is string
But it results in this error:

"SqlException: Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-8632-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16
When I look at the generated SQL, I can see EF has set all the Id's as NVARCHAR,
WHERE ([Project1].[C10] IN (N'Id1', N'Id2', N'Id3', ..... , N'Id40000')

If I set them as VARCHAR and run the query directly against the database there's no problem.
WHERE ([Project1].[C10] IN ('Id1', 'Id2', 'Id3', ..... , 'Id40000')

So my question is, how can I force EF to use VARCHAR in the expression?

IN (<List of 40,000 values>) is not a good idea anyway, as documented. If you need to pass that many values, use a table type. Then the table type has the data type of the column(s) defined, and the problem you have is moot. Classic XY Problem.

This has nothing to do with VARCHAR vs NVARCHAR. You can't use 40K parameters in a query. Never mind that EF is an ORM, not an ETL tool, and loading 40K rows is 10000% an ETL job

This is an ETL job and shouldn't be using EF at all. What is the actual scenario? What's the source of the IDs? Depending on that you may need to write a SQL query that JOINs with the source of the data, a query using a TVP parameter (although 40K rows will result in a slow execution plan), or the IDs should be inserted into a staging and properly indexed table before JOINing. None of this has anything to do with EF. If you want to map the final results to objects you can use Dapper or SqlQuery

If you insist on using LINQ, use Chunk to split the IDs into batches of eg 1000 items and retrieve the batches one by one, eg foreach(var batch in ids.Chunk(1000)){ customers.AddRange(dbContext.Customers.Where(c => batch.Contains(c.Id)));}. Yes, it will be slow, but the entire idea of using any ORM for ETL is slow. The fast way that can scale to any number is to use SqlBulkCopy to store the IDs into a staging table and use FROM Target inner join stage on stage.ID=Target.ID

Don't the new versions of EF Core etc use openjson to be able to avoid this issues

@siggemannen that won't avoid the performance issues. The query will run slowly with the added cost of parsing a 40K JSON array with no indexing or statistics

both a theoretical and real case question not really. The problem has nothing to do with VARCHAR and there aren't any performance issues. Bad queries, missing indexes or mismatched collations cause performance problems, not the type. The parameter type won't change the column type or indexes. I noticed a significant performance diff you should ask about those queries so people can help solve those issues. StackOverflow uses SQL Server with nvarchar columns. SQL Server isn't a new database and supported Unicode from the very first version, so any problems were fixed decades ago

Can I force EF6 to use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR in QUERY expressions?

The table type parameter will have the data type defined, so if you INSERT a varchar or nvarchar is irrelevant, @kristoffer_o . INSERTing an nvarchar into a varchar column will result in a varchar value.

@PanagiotisKanavos A TVP can have a primary key and indexes defined, so won't be slow, I use it the whole time on large sets of data. And it definitely works fine with EF Core (usin a small amount of raw SQL composed into the rest of the query), I suspect EF6 would be the same although I haven't tried.

@Charlieface TVPs have no statistics so the optimizer assumes they have a single row. The overall performance depends on the target table too - it's one thing to incorrectly assume 1 row when the target has eg 40K rows and another thing if it has 1M rows. I use TVPs too to upsert eg lookup data but use staging tables to load data into big tables

What is the datatype of the C10 column in the database?

The datatype of C10 is VARCHAR(50)

Have you try to batch your data?
for example:
int batchSize = 1000;
var customers = new List<Customer>();

for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i += batchSize)
{
    var batchIds = ids.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
    customers.AddRange(dbContext.Customers.Where(c => batchIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToList());
}

or you can make temporary table to store your data and then proceed to your actual table.

First that's not batching at all, it's (slow) paging. Second, the problem is the 40K parameters, not the number or results. This won't run, for the same reason the original query can't run
